# Boundary Value Problem with Unknown Integration Interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, boundary-value-problem

In [this](https://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/che512/bvp_paper.pdf) paper (pg. 15), the propagation of nerve impulses is modeled as,

$$
y_1' = 3 (y_1 + y_2 - 1/3 y_1^3 - 1.3)
$$

$$
y_2' = -(y_1 - 0.7 + 0.8 y_2) / 3
$$

The period $T$ however is unknown. With change of parameter the equation is changed to,

$$
y_1' = 3 T (y_1 + y_2 - 1/3 y_1^3 - 1.3)
$$

$$
y_2' = -T (y_1 - 0.7 + 0.8 y_2) / 3
$$

$$
T' = 0
$$

where boundary conditions are,

$$
y_1(0) = y_1(1), \quad y_2(0) = y_2(1)
$$

All of this makes sense. But then the problem says "in order to eliminate degenerate solutions $y'(t) = 0$ and sols with $T=0$, we have to use $dy_2 / d\tau (0) = 1$". As a result a new boundary condition is added,

$$ -T(y_1(0) - 0.7 + 0.8 y_2 (0) / 3 = 1$$

I did not understand where this comes from. Why was 1 chosen, not zero, or any other value? How was the new boundary condition obtained?

If I had to guess a non-zero value was chosen to stop $T=0$ being picked as a solution? But doesn't that artificially push the solution certain set of values?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this book by Shampine, pg. 174,

https://www.mobt3ath.com/uplode/book/book-50091.pdf

I was able to solve the non-seperated version of the problem,

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

def fun(x, y, p):
    T = p[0]
    return np.vstack((
        3.0 * T *  (y[0] + y[1] - (y[0]**3)/3.0 - 1.3),
        -T / 3.0 * (y[0] - 0.7 + 0.8*y[1]) 
    ))

def bc(ya, yb, p):
    return np.array( [ ya[0], yb[0], ya[1]-yb[1] ]   )

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 5)
y[0] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)
y[1] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * x)
sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y, p=[2*np.pi])
print (sol.p)
```

which reports 10.71, the same value shared in the book.

Answer (score 1):

The system is autonomous, thus invariant under shifts of the initial time. This freedom is also reflected in the three components of the state. So to fix a specific solution, one would need another boundary condition that is not related to the periodicity. One could set $y_1(0)=0$ or better $y_1'(0)=0$ or $y_1'(0)=0$. But that is also satisfied by stationary solutions.

So setting $y_2'(0)$ to some fixed non-zero value will prevent finding stationary solutions. However you are right, it seems to be a lucky guess that this value $1$ will give a solution at all. As a periodic solution, the component $y_2$ will have extrema where the derivative is zero, so setting the derivative to some smaller value would appear to give a greater chance to actually find a solution.

As the solution plot shows,

[image]

the $y_2$ range includes $[0.5,2]$. This gives by the mean value theorem derivatives for unit parameter $\tau$ including the range $[-1.5,1.5]$. So setting the derivative to $b=1$ is a safe choice to target this solution. As the first plot shows, these different solutions for different choices of $y_2'(0)=b$ give the same curve in the phase space, just started at a different point.

The paper only gives a demonstration of the method, so that it is sufficient that the given parameters indeed lead to the presented solution.

Comment: I searched some more, found this book https://www.mobt3ath.com/uplode/book/book-50091.pdf by the same author. But on pg 175 book gives completely different approach! There is more explanation here tho, maybe I should adapt this one.

Comment: Shampine is the author of the Matlab ODE solver package, so yes, you will find other related publications by this author. As you can see from the vagueness of my answer, the selection of the third condition is more-or-less a lucky guess, smooth functions on a compact set have a compact range and thus lots of values outside it.

Comment: @BBDynSys : Note that the method used in the book is to set $y_1(0)=0$, which was the first mentioned variant in the answer. This requires that you were lucky enough in the guess of the range of $y_1$ for the periodic solution, for instance the range of $y_2$ does not contain the value $0$. Of course, if you have an unique equilibrium point, then the periodic solution must circle around it and thus have points where one coordinate coincides with the same of the equilibrium point.

Comment: I was able to compute a non-seperated solution for the problem, based on $y_1(0)=0$. If I had to reason backwards, since the soln is periodic, we just pick a starting place and the rest of the function will shift accordingly and we are looking for $T$ anyway.